# Different name on terminal than on file manager

Tags: terminal, gnome, nautilus

I work on RedHat Linux and, when I read files from terminal using `ll` or `ls -l` on my desktop, I see different names from what I have in my file manager. Say the file name on desktop is `John`, but I see it in the terminal as `vc-john.desktop`. Can I get some help over here please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're observing is a common behavior in many Linux distributions, including Red Hat. The discrepancy in file names between the graphical file manager and the terminal is due to the way desktop environments handle desktop entries (.desktop files).

Here's an explanation:

**Desktop Files (*.desktop):** These are special files in Linux that act as shortcuts to applications, similar to shortcuts in Windows. They are plain text files, but with a .desktop extension. These files typically reside in /usr/share/applications/ for system-wide applications or ~/.local/share/applications/ for user-specific applications. They can also be placed on the Desktop for quick access.

**Naming Convention:** In the file manager (like GNOME's Nautilus or KDE's Dolphin), these files are displayed with the name specified inside the .desktop file, not the actual filename. For example, a file named vc-john.desktop might contain a line like Name=John. The file manager shows "John" based on the Name property in the file.

**Terminal View (ll or ls -l):** When you use commands like ls -l or ll in the terminal, you see the actual file names on the filesystem, not the names specified inside the .desktop files. That's why you see vc-john.desktop instead of "John".

**Modifying Display Names:** If you want to change how a name is displayed in the file manager, you can edit the .desktop file and modify the Name field. However, this won't change the actual filename, which is what you see in the terminal.

**Why the Prefix?:** The prefix (like vc- in your case) is often used for organizational or naming convention purposes, especially if the desktop files are generated by specific software or scripts.

In summary, the file manager is showing a user-friendly name extracted from the .desktop file's content, while the terminal is showing the actual filename on the filesystem. This behavior is by design to make the desktop more user-friendly and does not indicate any problem with your system.

Comment: Thank you @Kristtof V88 for your reply. I understand it now.

Answer (score 2):

The name you see in the terminal will always be the real one. Presumably, your file manager is hiding the extension. Then, since this is a `.desktop` file, it probably contains its own display name which is what will be shown. For example, if I create a file named `Desktop/vc-john.desktop` with the following contents:

```
$ cat Desktop/vc-john.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Name=John
Exec=true
Comment=
Terminal=false
PrefersNonDefaultGPU=false
Icon=cinnamon-panel-launcher
Type=Application
```

Then, because of `Name=John`, the file manager will display it as `John` because it knows about `.desktop` files, but the shell (the terminal), which does not know about them, will show it as `vc-john.desktop`.

[image: screenshot showing the different file names in terminal and file manager]

Comment: Thank you @tredon. Your answer is highly appriciated.